# EF 6 Future Query and Cache don't work together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, caching

How can I use [Second Level Cache](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache) with the Entity Framework [extension](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) for future query?

With my code if I use the `Future()` extension the query will never be cached.

```
public IEnumerable<Service> GetServices(EnumAccountType accountType)
{
    return UnitOfWork.Context.Services
                     .Where(s => s.UserTypeId == (int)accountType)
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .Cached()
                     .Future();

}
```